# Synchronization and time keeping of multiple applications

Tags: actionscript-3, tcp, synchronization, air, real-time

How would I implement a system that will keep 20 applications running on a closed network to stay synchronized whilst performing various tasks?

Each application will be identical, on an identical machine. These machines will have a socket connection to the master application that will issue TCP commands to the units such as  `Play:"Video1.mp4"`. It is vital that these videos are played at the same time and keep time with each other.

The only difference between each unit is that the window will be offset on the desktop, so that each one has a different view port on the application - as this will be used in a multi-projector set up.

any solutions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it some years ago. 5 computers running 5 instances of the same flash app. Evey app was displaying a "slice" of the same huge app and everything needed to be synchronized at fractions of seconds precision.

I used a simple Python script (running on a 6th machine) that was sending OSC messages on the local network. the flash apps were listening through FLOSC to this packets, and were sending to the Python script message about their status.

The stuff was running at the Withney Museum (NY) and at Palais de Tokyo (Paris), so I'm quite confident about the solution :) I hope it helps you

Comment: great sounds encouraging - how was the python script designed to compensate if one of the instance was out of sync?

Comment: I didn't write the python part personally, but basically every instance of the Flash app had a unique ID, and when one of the instance was out of sync, the python was waiting for it to be finished before sending to the other instances the command to go on. I don't remember any instance getting slower than other, but I wrote in the Flash app a special method to "fade out" the actual state just in case it happened

Comment: Do you think the following idea would make any sense? Have the master app continuously boradcast a timestamp every n milliseconds to the clients via udp, and whenever an action needs to be started, send the command via tcp to the clients along the lines of `play movie1 when timestamp >= n`

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question. The idea I suggest means: 1) clients are waiting for instructions; 2) the server app (python) broadcasts OSC packets containing the command to be executed by the clients. the time schedule of sending the packets is handled by the python part;  3) everytime a client finishes the execution of a part, it sends back via OSC a message to the server; 4) when the server has received the "done" message from all clients, send the next message. Really hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep tracking and latest updated data in your master application. you have to broadcast your newly updated data to all connected client to deliver updated data. after any update from any client you have to send updated data to all connected clients.

In FMS remote shared object is used to maintain data centrally across the network connected application via FMS. when any client is sending any updated OnSync Event is fired to all client application and data is sync with FMS Remote Shared Object. So this kind of Flow you have to develop for proper synchronization of data across network.

you can also use the RPC system to sync data between all connected application to the Master application. in that you have to init RPC to the client to Master application to send data update and Master application send RPC to all other client which are connected to the Master application.